# How to exit "mysql.exe" process by writing to its input stream (Process Created using CreateProcess() )

Tags: c++, mysql

I'm trying to to exit `mysql.exe` gracefully which is created using `CreateProcess()` from Windows APIs. My problem is `mysql.exe` is not killed. If I kill the process after sleeping my main thread for some time then the "dump" of database I'm writing to its INPUT stream (using pipes) is not applied properly.

I was sending `FLUSH TABLES; EXIT;` as the last commands to input stream.

Comment: Could you post your code, and specifically what was the command line you ran? (any flags set etc) or Config options

Comment: Also, what happens when you send "FLUSH_TABLES; EXIT;" - to me that would be the right sort of thing to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two answers:

1. Using `FLUSH TABLES;EXIT;\n` while writing to the Input file stream. Working fine
2. Inherit handles
   Use Security Attributes and `SetHandleInformation()`. Please refer to msdn for this

Answer (score 1):

Don't kill the process using `TerminateProcess`.

Instead send your `FLUSH_TABLES; EXIT;` commands, and use `WaitForSingleObject(hProcess)` to wait for it to finish doing what it was doing.

Comment: @sreekar Process handles are set to a signalled state when their process exits. Waiting for the process handle waits for it to exit.

Comment: @Sreekar, what are you doing with the output from the MySQL process? You must read all the output from STDOUT and STDERR or the MySQL process will be waiting for you.

Comment: @Ben I'm reading STDOUT and STDERR only if any error occurs. I don't need them in my application. When I close the handle after inheriting things are fine as ReadFile (open() system call from linux) will fail So mysql.exe is exiting...Thank you so much Ben for your time and patience..